# Synthetic scene stack (history) with React Native Router Flux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, persistence, react-native-router-flux

Is there any way how to synthetically define scene stack (history) with React Native Router Flux? Let's say I have an app, where the user can naturally navigate from `A –> B –> C`. I'd like to initiate app on scene C, which has the same history as natural behavior (`A -> B -> C`), so user navigates back to `B` from initially opened scene `C`.

**EDIT**: I guess it should be somehow achievable by using Redux Persist, but I've found this related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527313/router-state-not-being-persisted-in-react-native-with-redux).

Comment: Can you confirm if this will be the first screen of the app?

Comment: Yes, `C` would be the first screen of the app.

Comment: This is possible with ex-navigation where you can provide a navigation stack and index of the stack to show via immediatelyresetstack method. Couldn't find any such thing in react native router flux.

Comment: One way I could think of is, use "react-native-splash-screen" for splash screen of the app. And inside componentDidMount of A based on some global check of app start, push B and similarly inside componentDidMount of B based on same check, push C. You can then remove the splash screen in componentDidMount of scene C (this splash library allows you to run the app behind splash screen and remove it anywhere you want) and also change the global variable of app start so that they don't get pushed when you use them again inside app with some other flow. Will that work for you?

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: No, I haven't since I don't want to pre-initialise stack (B and A screen) before C pops to B. I'll give a try to `ex-navigation`

Comment: @irfan-ayaz Could you provide example code for `ex-navigation`, please?

Comment: https://github.com/exponent/ex-navigation

Comment: I can try and get it to work with ex-navigation if you are interested in that.

Comment: Sure, please try.

Comment: @IrfanAyaz I've already tried to get ex-navigation and redux-persist working, but I'm getting `store.subscribe is not function` error with this code https://gist.github.com/sealskej/c7580d4fe34760b4ae5767487e5d1755

Comment: I managed to do it with `ex-navigation` and `immediatelyResetStack` here https://gist.github.com/sealskej/a981e61d52567bcfeeacc9ade3ab3e0c Thanks @IrfanAyaz!

Comment: But it pre-initialise B and A, so their `componentDidMount()` and `render()` are called after stack reset.

Comment: Do i get the bounty then? if your problem is resolved?

Comment: @IrfanAyaz Thank you, it's a good and working advice, but unfortunately it doesn't apply to the original question related to RN Router Flux.

Comment: Great that you got it working!

Comment: Can I do the same with the new React Navigation (https://reactnavigation.org)?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it with a fake empty initial scene. It's very hacky solution and animation from C to B still doesn't work correctly.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {AppRegistry} from "react-native";
import {Scene, Router, Actions, ActionConst} from "react-native-router-flux";
import A from "./A";
import B from "./B";
import C from "./C";

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const params = {
      onBack: () => Actions.b({
        direction: 'fade',
        onBack: () => Actions.a({
          direction: 'fade'
        })
      }),
      duration: 0
    };
    Actions.c(params);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Scene key="root" style={{paddingTop: 60}}>
            <Scene key="empty"
                   component={class extends Component{render() {return null}}}
                   />
            <Scene key="a" component={A} title='A' type={ActionConst.RESET}/>
            <Scene key="b" component={B} title='B'/>
            <Scene key="c" component={C} title='C'/>
          </Scene>
        </Router>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('untitled', () => App);
```